# Mysql, copy a cell value from another row in the same table

Tags: mysql

How to copy a cell value from another row in the same table?

```
UPDATE mytable SET myvalue=(SELECT myvalue FROM mytable WHERE id=2) WHERE id=11
```

It gives an error message:

```
Table 'mytable' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the `id=11`?

Comment: You need `WHERE` before `id=11`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET id=11, mycol=a.mycol FROM (SELECT mycol FROM mytable WHERE id=2) a
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it also gives an error.